# Fontawesome icons not working in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am designing wordpress theme and I have downloaded fontawesome css file (.css & .min.css). I linked them properly and I can even see these files are added in header section by inspecting the source code after saving the file.

My theme is just to complete except these icons.
I have used  and even "fad", "fab", "far", "fal", "fas" but nothing happened. The place of the icon appears in a small rectangle.
[image: fontawesome icon]

Comment: Should you use only **fa** instead of "fad", "fab", "far", "fal", "fas" . **for example**  `<i class="fa fa-user">User Icon</i>`

Comment: Please show your HTML codes, including the `<head>`

Comment: @esel which version your using font awesome4 or 5.

Comment: Head link here https://i.ibb.co/t2fJWHq/fontawesome-link.png and HTML code used. I have used fa, fas...so I can get if only one is wrong https://i.ibb.co/D1tB1z7/fontawesome-i.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'fa' or you have checked its version is it new or old 
For old version you can add class `<i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>`
For new version you can add class `<i class="fas fa-circle"></i>`